# How to make UserForm invoked from its parent file visible in all opened workbooks and enable selecting cells by InputBox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, vba7

I am working in Excel 365. I have a UserForm which lists all sheet names in target workbook (Name from a textbox). But the UserForm should be able to invoke from its parent file **too** (the file that contains the UserForm).

The problem is if I invoke the UserForm from its parent file and activate the target workbook (Name from a textbox) the UserForm stays with its parent file. I can only see the Userform if I activate its parent file or Alt + Tab. I tried as below.

```
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
Workbooks(txtTargetFileName.Text).Activate
```

How can I make the UserForm visible to all the opened workbook or atleast in the target workbook and enable selecting cells by InputBox?

[image]

Comment: I expect you need this: https://jkp-ads.com/articles/keepuserformontop01.asp

Comment: @jkpieterse. Looks like it will work. I will give it a try.